# Java RestTemplate how to POST with body

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

I need some assistance on the correct way to POST a json body with RestTemplate within a RestController. I am just not familiar enough as to what I am doing wrong. I have spent to much time looking at this and I am not getting the result I need. Hopefully the info I provide is clear. As of right now I am just trying to POST the JSON body to the below URL API

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/feedback")
public class FeedbackController {

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public FeedbackController(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }
  
  @RequestMapping(          
            method = RequestMethod.POST
            )
  public IncidentReport createIncident()      
  {  
      
    return restTemplate.exchange(
        "URL_API/create",
        HttpMethod.POST, null,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<IncidentReport>(){}
                
    ).getBody();
  }
```

**JSON POST BODY**

```
 {
"group": "my_group",
"short_description":"this is a test for the short description",
"contact_type":"Alert",
 }
```

Comment: Can you add the output/error you get?

Comment: @Thirumal it returns an empty records:{} array as if it did not take the post body. If I take the API URL and add it into postman with the same JSON Body it works with no issues. But doesn't work when I try to use my Request Mapping POST call

Answer (score 1):

`exchange` is the low-level method, and the more specific ones are usually more friendly as long as they cover your use case. You're looking for a `postForObject` (`postForEntity` if you need the headers):

```
return restTemplate.postForObject(url, incidentObject, IncidentReport.class);
```

Comment: dumb  question but what would be my incidentObject...?

Comment: @RobDePietro You said you were going to use `RestTemplate` to post _something_.

Comment: 1st parameter is url
2nd parameter is Java Object mapped from your request Json which you want to post
3rd parameter is type of response you are expecting from called service

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- isn't the post json post body that is supplied with the http post call my incidentObject?

Comment: @RobDePietro Are you perhaps confusing the role of `RestTemplate`? Its job is for you to _make HTTP calls_ to some API; if you are _handling incoming HTTP calls_, then that's not the tool you need.

Answer (score -1):

StackTrace would have been more helpful. I think you should instantiate RestTemplate in below manner.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder
            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
            .build();
}
```

Then AutoWire it in your Controller class

```
 @Autowired
private RestTemplate myRestTemplate;
```

Ensure Jackson library is present in the classpath. Try to use myRestTemplate.postForObject(). There is not much to this. If you are still getting an issue try to analyze stack trace, you will get some hint.

Answer (score -1):

Since spring boot autoconfigures `RestTemplate` and `ObjectMapper` to serialize/deserialize in your `@RestController` endpoints you don't have to stick with `RestTemplate` at all and can use functionality as show in the following code snippet:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/feedback")
public class FeedbackController {

    @Autowired private FeedbackFacade feedbackFacade;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<IncidentReport> createIncidentReport(
            @RequestBody IncidentReport incidentReport)
    {
        log.info("Create incident report {}", incidentReport);
        var createdIncidentReport = feedbackFacade.create(incidentReport);
        log.info("Created incident report: {}", createdIncidentReport);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdIncidentReport, HttpStatus.CREATED)
    }
}
```